# How to add row selection checkbox for ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

Is there a way to have row selection checkbox for each row without configuring a special column for it? I mean to add propertie for my gridOptions and to see checkbox near each row, then to get all selected rows? 
All the documentation I read is showing how to do it by adding it to specific column.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can still have row selection without having a checkbox column - you can either simply have selection based on row selection, or have a column render with a checkbox in it (with a custom cell renderer).

Take a look at the [Selection Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/) for more information about row selection, and at the [Cell Rendering Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/) about cell rendering

Comment: ag-grid don't have an api to select entire row by checkbox?

Comment: You can react on events such as cellClicked or rowClicked, and once called you can in turn call node.setSelected(true) (for example)

Comment: OK...thanks. We also would like to buy ag-grid license to use some of your enterprise features, but I found out this is not so easy, can you contact me with your sales?

Comment: Hi - please contact us at accounts@ag-grid.com - they'll be able to help you there, including more support if needed. Let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late to answer on this post. But It may help someone who look for solution still. It works with checkbox selection on each row (click anywhere on the row to select checkbox), shift/control and toggle selection. Here I have given only necessary code.

```
vm.gridOptions = {
  appSpecific  : {},
  onRowClicked : onRowClicked,
  onGridReady : function() {
    let api = vm.gridApi = vm.gridOptions.api;
  }
};

function toggleSelect(row) {
  row.node.setSelected(!row.node.isSelected(), false);
}


function onRowClicked(row) {
  var appSpecific = vm.gridOptions.appSpecific;
  var lastSelectedRow = appSpecific.lastSelectedRow;
  var shiftKey = row.event.shiftKey;

  // if not modifier keys are clicked toggle row
  if (!shiftKey) {
    toggleSelect(row);
  } else if (lastSelectedRow !== undefined) {

    if (shiftKey) {
      var startIndex, endIndex;
      // Get our start and end indexes correct
      if (row.rowIndex < lastSelectedRow.rowIndex) {
        startIndex = row.rowIndex;
        endIndex = lastSelectedRow.rowIndex;
      }
      else {
        startIndex = lastSelectedRow.rowIndex;
        endIndex = row.rowIndex;
      }
      // Select all the rows between the previously selected row and the
      // newly clicked row
      for (var i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
        vm.gridApi.selectIndex(i, true, true);
      }
    }
  }
  // Store the recently clicked row for future use
  appSpecific.lastSelectedRow = row;
  getSelection(); // Implement functionality to get selected rows 
}
```